# Arduino UNO reiniciando sozinho

Tags: arduino

Boa tarde, tenho um arduino UNO, e uma shield GSM ICOMSAT 1.1 aqui, estava trabalhando normalmente com os dois, recebendo e enviando SMSs, porém quando adicionei uma shield SD Card para gerar um datalogger o arduino fica reiniciando sozinho. 
Então testei somente o SD Card, e funcionou perfeitamente. Mas a shield GSM e a Shield SD Card não funcionam juntas. Alguem sabe pq?

Imagem do Monitor Serial:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Usado: [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/marcobosa/42ad6047d4f8e75e3268)

O engraçado que se eu comentar essa parte do código:

```
myFile = SD.open("dados.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (myFile){                                     
  Serial.print("Escrevendo em arquivo...");     //Escreve no arquivo
  myFile.println("hello SD Card Shield!");      //Teste de escrita

  myFile.close();                               //Fecha o arquivo
  Serial.println("Escrita finalizada");         //Informa escrita finalizada
}else{
  Serial.println("Erro ao abrir arquivo");      //Informa que há algum erro
}
```

Dai o arduino nao reinicia, porem, nao consigo fazer a escrita dos dados no arquivo .txt.

Comment: Erros de reinicialização do Arduino são comuns quando ele atinge o limite da corrente, na pratica, ele não consegue alimentar os periféricos e a ele mesmo, e acaba reiniciando. É possível que quando ele tente escrever no SD, o shield exija mais corrente e o Arduino não aguente. (estou baseando essa resposta em experiências com outros periféricos) Experimente alimentar um dos shields com uma fonte diferente, e veja se o problema persiste. (Se for daqueles shields que encaixam, totalmente, faça um jumper dos pinos que precisar para comunicação, e coloque os de alimentação na outra fonte de 5v).

Comment: Você chegou a formatar o SD em Fat16 ou Fat32? Porque ele só suporta estes formatos. Pode ser também que seja a questão de excesso de corrente, para tirar esta dúvida conecte uma fonte externa no arduino.

Comment: Se estiver usando alimentação USB provavelmente o problema é esse, use alimentação pelo jack